# Magento setting under web : Use HTTP Only: No / Yes

Tags: magento-1.9

I have install SSL certificate on my server in which magento setup is already install. 
I have done almost everything. But don't know what to choose from **HTTP Only** field .

**System -> config -> web**

Field name: Use HTTP Only

What should i choose from **Use HTTP Only** field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just go into **System -> config -> web** and add http before url for **Base URL** field under **Unsecure** and **Secure** Tab

Then your site will work with Http

Answer (score 0):

You want to always have that set to yes, it's a vulnerability if it's not.

Here is some more information and a link to a good resource:

> HTTP-only cookies aren’t accessible via JavaScript through the 
>   Document.cookie property, the XMLHttpRequest and Request APIs to 
>   prevent attacks against cross-site scripting (XSS).
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives

https://maxchadwick.xyz/blog/magentos-use-http-only-cookie-setting